# Basic CSS issue, spacing at the top of the page

Tags: html, css

I've just starting making a website and I've got stuck on a basic part and I can't think of the solution for the life of me. What I am trying to do it remove the space at the top but I haven't set anything to cause this. Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

http://jsfiddle.net/mexicanbandit/f0hdqcgu/6/

```
body {
    background-color: #307189;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 48rem;
    width: 90%;
}

/***** header *****/
header {
    background-color: #A2CEDD;
}

h1 {
    font: 7rem Champagne and Limousines, sans-serif;
    color: #00668C;
}
```

Comment: The space is due to the default margins on your `<h1>`. See [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<h1>` elements have a default margin. You can remove it by adding `margin:0`:

```
h1 {
    font: 7rem Champagne and Limousines, sans-serif;
    color: #00668C;
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f0hdqcgu/8/)**

You might also want to check into CSS resets which will try and normalize the CSS differences between browsers.

Comment: I've been racking my brain for a while trying to figure it out :) Thanks for the quick reply, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

By default a `h1` has a margin around it. You can see this if you inspect it with the browser dev tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>.)

You need to set its css to `margin:0;` or `margin-top:0;` to get rid of this.

```
h1 {
    font: 7rem Champagne and Limousines, sans-serif;
    color: #00668C;
    margin:0;
}
```

The `body` will also have a small margin or padding, so if you want to remove all space, you can also set this to 0. A standard thing to do to deal with browser variations is this:

```
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0hdqcgu/7/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the huge margins your h1 has. You could set the margin to 0 for example:

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added margin:0; and line-height:90% to your  tag.

```
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 48rem;
    width: 90%;
}
/***** header *****/
 header {
    background-color: #A2CEDD;
}
h1 {
    margin:0;
    font: 7rem Champagne and Limousines, sans-serif;
    line-height: 90%;
    color: #00668C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for remove all space try

```
body {
    background-color: #307189;
    margin: 0px;padding: 0px; /*add*/
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 48rem;
    width: 90%;
}
/***** header *****/
 header {
    background-color: #A2CEDD;
}
h1 {
    font: 7rem Champagne and Limousines, sans-serif;
    color: #00668C;
    margin: 0px;padding: 0px; /*add*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/f0hdqcgu/19/